# Is it possible to override the HTTP functions in wxHtmlWindow?

Tags: wxwidgets, libcurl, wxhtmlwindow

I would like wxHtmlWindow to use libcurl instead of the internal wxHTTP class.

Is there an easy way to do this? If not, can I at least change the useragent wxHtmlWindow sends when it accesses pages?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class that manage my curl session. Setting a user agent, cookies, server to connect to etc.

Also I would make that class to be able to save the page I get from the internet to a file `temp/web.htm`

and then I would use something like:

```
htmlwin->LoadPage("temp/web.htm");
```

Where `htmlwin` is a `wxHtmlWindow`

This is the first thing that comes in my mind, maybe I can think to a better solution.

EDIT 1:
See [this link](http://computingfunnyfacts.blogspot.com/2007/05/c-curl-wrapper.html) so see a little example of wrapping curl in a C++ class

Comment: That was my initial idea too. But then what happens with images referenced in the HTML document?